# Java based Standalone application

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am developing a standalone application for a client using Java Swing and jdbc with MySQL. I am using MySQL as the database.I want to know that how the client can install MySQL, is there a way by which the client can install MySQL in his machine,or can i distribute the MySQL setup.The client just needs the software running and do not want to go to any installation process.

What is the way around with that??

Comment: I would say so, since many apps use MySQL (or SQLite).

Answer (score 3):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to launch the app.

The MySQL installer can be invoked from an `installer-desc` element in the launch file.  Here is my [demo. of the JNLP API ExtensionInstallerService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).

Answer (score 2):

You're likely to find H2, HSQLDB, Derby, or SQLite to be more suitable for your deployment.  They're intended to be embedded in other applications.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the simplest solution, but it is a good idea to have an installer for your application, which would take care of MySQL installation. IzPack is a very reasonable installation tool, which can execute external applications (e.g. MySQL installer) as part of the installation process. [This](http://groups.google.com/group/izpack-user/browse_thread/thread/54b617819f957bac/b76f48d1003c31cd?lnk=raot&pli=1) discussion might be of some interest.

However, as mentioned in other replies, the use of an embedded RDBMS such as H2, SQLite etc., is a better choice than MySQL for a standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

Few portable database alternatives: [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).