# How to Export Netbeans Java project and database in MySql together to work on different machines?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

I have created a ResultSystem project in Java swings using netbeans. My backend system is Mysql database. I have cleaned and build the jar file in netbeans which works fine on my computer.

However i want to run this jar file on multiple machines which works fine for the UI in java but i am pretty sure the mysql database wont work if i file a query on other system, does this mean i need mysql installed on all the machine and need to recreate the database on every new machine i run this jar file ?

Is there a way i can group the package together and send it as a single Jar file ?

Any help or suggestion please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to deploy your jar file to many machines . 
but first of all ,

You have two steps:

1: 
Before you can connect to a MySQL Database Server, you must first ensure that the MySQL Database Server is running on the machine you are deploying on .

2:
After that you need to create DB tables (you can run a single DB script file to create your DB). this is an the easy part .

Also read this : 
[How to create installer once finished with Java Desktop Application with MySQL DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150146/how-to-create-installer-once-finished-with-java-desktop-application-with-mysql-d)

and

[Java application and MySQL installation in a single package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731279/java-application-and-mysql-installation-in-a-single-package)